# Deleting, editing and sharing individual videos within a list

Tags: video

I have a list of video thumbnails that users need to be able to edit, delete and share. The issue is that only one video at a time can be edited or shared, but multiple videos can be deleted at a time

I've considered placing check boxes next to each video thumbnail and allowing the user to tick these check boxes in accordance to which video they'd like to apply the options to. This isn't very practical due to the fact users can't edit and share more than one video.

Option 2 allows users to edit, delete and share individual videos by clicking a button placed next to each individual video thumbnail (see the image below).

Is this more relevant to what i am trying to achieve?

[image]

Comment: I think you've answered your question because users can not do a bulk select. As a result, your "direct manipulation" method will work best.

Comment: @usingtheinternet - +1, "You've already undone your vote on this comment; you cannot upvote it again." sorry, i mistakenly double clicked! Direct manipulation should be the obvious choice though.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @usingtheinternet , and presumably your own instincts, the second option is more expressive of the actual action going on. That said there are a few things that would be more relevant in my opinion.

- Clicking the pencil/edit button should simply replace the current video item with the same form controls you have from any editor page. Inline-editing.
- You should combine the first option and allow mass delete.
- If you do both of these, you can actually enable mass editing by switching all checked lines with the form elements and creating a bulk update script. (you could have an edit page which produces a form region for each element submitted)
- You might extend your features to include a playlist, then  you could add "share as playlist" for mass sharing.

This point would be a neat feature if you had the time but I think not quite as much so as the other points, which you basically have the code and controls for already.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 is better. You can do one more thing: display the action icons on hover. That would help to reduce clutter on the UI.